# Find function with given properties

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, convex-analysis

Find a smooth function $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ that

- domain $g$ is $\mathbb{R}$
- range of $g$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R^+}$
- $g$ is concave.

Comment: @Adam The only example I can come up with is a constant function. But I am looking for more interesting functions.

Comment: @Adam Do you know any other example?

Comment: Only constant functions satisfy all the requirements.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks. Why is it so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $g$ is concave and non-constant. Then we have $x_1 < x_2$ such that $g(x_1) \neq g(x_2)$. Without loss of generality (eg, take $x \mapsto g(-x)$ instead) we may assume $g(x_1)<g(x_2)$.

Let $x< x_1$. Then if $\lambda = \frac{x_1-x}{x_2-x}$, we have $x_1 = (1-\lambda) x + \lambda x_2$, and so $g(x_1) \ge (1-\lambda) g(x) + \lambda g(x_2)$. Rearranging gives $\frac{x_2 g(x_1)-x_1g(x_2)+x(g(x_2)-g(x_1))}{x_2-x_1} \ge g(x)$, from which it follows that $\lim_{x \to -\infty} g(x) = -\infty$.

Hence if $g$ is concave, defined on $\mathbb{R}$, and bounded below, it must be constant.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just a small question. Why \begin{equation}\frac{x_2 g(x_1)-x_1g(x_2)+x(g(x_2)-g(x_1))}{x_2-x_1} \ge g(x),\end{equation} implies that \begin{equation}\lim_{x \to -\infty} g(x) = -\infty? \end{equation}Is it because everything in RHS except $x$ is fixed, so we can push $x$, so that the RHS becomes $-\infty$?

Comment: By assumption $g(x_2)-g(x_1) >0$ and $x_2-x_1 >0$, so if $x \to -\infty$, then $x \frac{g(x_2)-g(x_1)}{x_2-x_1} \to - \infty$.

Comment: I think your proof works even if $g$ is not smooth, right?

Comment: Correct, the proof does not rely on any smoothness hypotheses. (However, a convex or concave function defined on $\mathbb{R}$ can be shown to be continuous.)